# Configuring rlm_rest module in FreeRadius for accounting

Tags: freeradius, json, process-accounting

I'm upgrading from *FreeRadius 2* to *FreeRadius 3* and changing some  integration point from `sql` to `rest` module.

Actually, I have two **accounting** points: `accounting_start_query` and `accounting_start_query`, which are calls to procedures.

Now, I need to configure `accounting` in rlm_rest module FreeRadius.

This [code](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/rest) didn't mention the start/stop operations. Should I implement both ?

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

`rlm_rest` is designed to be a transport for AVPs it doesn't really implement session management logic in the same way as `rlm_sql`.

When `rlm_sql` gets an interim it hasn't seen a start for it'll automatically create a record for that session.

With `rlm_rest` all that logic is up to the rest API you're calling.  All `rlm_rest` will do is serialize the attributes that FreeRADIUS received in the `Access-request` and send them to an API endpoint.

It's up to you whether you use different endpoints for start/interim/stop packets.  If you do want to, you can use the expansion `%{Acct-Status-Type}` in the URL string to get what type of packet it was.

At a high level RADIUS accounting doesn't really map to RESTfull design perfectly. You don't know whether you need to `PUT` or `POST` requests, because you don't know whether you're creating an object or updating a pre-existing one.

The most robust design would be one that used a single endpoint with `%{Acct-Unique-Session-ID}` as the object identifier, accepted `PUT` or `POST` methods interchangeably, and did the REST equivalent of "upserts", ignoring requests where `Event-Timestamp` is older than the last received `Event-Timestamp`.

Comment: I didn't get how accept both methods as you suggested, because I configure in the module the (only) http method to be dispatched. I think PUT is the best choice in this case.

Comment: Accepting both HTTP methods would be something specific to the REST framework you're using.